# Mocking audio in python with PhantomJS WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, audio, mocking, phantomjs

I was trying to switch from FireFox testing to PhantomJS headless browser on Python. The main problem started once the product under test produced a sound and test process stuck. In `ghostdriver.log` the following error:

```
[ERROR - 2015-06-12T13:06:45.972Z] Session [d6f9d720-1103-11e5-8641-053d1e189dc8] - page.onError - msg: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.context.createGain')

:262 in error
[ERROR - 2015-06-12T13:06:45.972Z] Session [d6f9d720-1103-11e5-8641-053d1e189dc8] - page.onError - stack:
Sound (http://localhost:7777/lib/phaser.js:57271)
add (http://localhost:7777/lib/phaser.js:58674)
audio (http://localhost:7777/lib/phaser.js:36560)
(anonymous function) (http://localhost:7777/src/main/common/setup.js:105)
forEach (:0)
create (http://localhost:7777/src/main/common/setup.js:104)
loadComplete (http://localhost:7777/lib/phaser.js:18360)
finishedLoading (http://localhost:7777/lib/phaser.js:55951)
processLoadQueue (http://localhost:7777/lib/phaser.js:55906)
asyncComplete (http://localhost:7777/lib/phaser.js:55979)
fileComplete (http://localhost:7777/lib/phaser.js:56625)
onload (http://localhost:7777/lib/phaser.js:56190)

262 in error
```

I know that PhantomJS is not supporting Audio so far, and as the audio is not the issue I would like to test the question is: any possibility to mock audio in python using `selenium`? How to do this?